# Opposite of findall

Tags: prolog

I would like to know how to do the opposite of findall (that are not used) in prolog.For example, If I have the following predicats :

```
vegetable('salad','green').
vegetable('tomato','red').
vegetable('avocado','red').
meal('Simple salad','salad','tomato').
findall(X(meal(_,X,_),vegetable(X,_)),listOfVegetables).
```

I would need something opposite to the find all in the code overhead.

I would like to like to find all the vegetables not contained in a meal (so in this case avocado).

Comment: This is a little confusing. What does `meal` look like in general? Is it always the name of a meal followed by two vegetables? Perhaps then, `findall(V, (vegetable(V, _), \+meal(_,V,_), \+meal(_,_,V)), Veggies)`. (NOTE that `listOfVegetables` is *not* a valid Prolog variable, and `X(meal(_,X,_),vegetable(X,_))` is invalid Prolog syntax.)

Comment: I'd say: You do not need any `findall/3`. Instead, just use the toplevel.